# Problems running application compiled with XCode 3.2.4 and iOS SDK 4.1 on iOS 3.x

Tags: iphone, linker, ios4

I recently ran into troubles building an app with latest iOS 4.1 SDK and running it on device with iOS 3.x. App works OK on 4.x devices and iPad, but crashes on devices running older 3.x iOS.

Problem appears to be in linker, since crashes are obviously caused by calls to 3rd party libraries used in the project. The linker (or even compiler) suspicion is supported by fact that when I build the app with older 3.1.3 SDK, it works as expected.

My Release configuration uses iOS 4.1 as Base SDK and iOS 3.0 as deployment target platform, compiled with LLVM GCC 4.2. I also tried GCC 4.2 compiler, but it didn't help too.

I've found that there's some bug in linker/compiler in this version of SDK, but none of proposed solutions worked for me.

I desperately need to resolve this issue, so any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks to everyone for any hint or advice.

Comment: You need to accept some answers to your questions. All you need to do is to press the checkmark next to the answer that you think helped you fix the problem. This will reward the user who spent time on helping you, and you will also get a small reward.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know that if you are using something like iAd framework, you need to add this framework as "weak dependency" in the Target Info Pop-Up :-)

If it's a librairie, could you list them ?

Good Luck !

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but this is not the case, no iAd fw is used. The app uses Three20 and some library for handling Zip archives. No matter if I define it as weak or required dependency, the result is the same. As I wrote above, it works on iOS 4.x and 3.2 devices, but not on iOS <3.2. First call to linked library causes crash. When I build the app with 3.1.3 SDK, it works on 3.0 normally. I assume it needs to adjust some linker or compiler flags, but I cannot figure out WHICH and HOW?!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am too late at answering this one. But still - If you have the 3.1.3 device with you, doing an in-system debugging by loading an app with a developer profile gives you what caused the crash. I faced a similar problem when my apps used to work fine on the 4.0+ devices but used to crash immediately upon startup when I tried it on 3.1.2 device. I compiled it with a developer profile and then did an in-system debugging. I found out that I was using a class UIPopoverController which was brought in with iOS 3.2 and hence used to fail for my 3.1.2. Putting in the necessary checks for this resolved my problem.

Hope that helps.